# Angular/Ionic: How to show my spinner while components are loading

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, spinner

I use `ng-repeat` to display many items and I want to show the `ion-spinner` if there is any item that is loading.

This is my `Ionic` template:

```
<div>
  <ion-spinner icon="ripple"></ion-spinner>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item
    ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-show="rendered">
    <mycomp on-render="rendered = $(completed)"></myomp>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

`<mycomp>` is a custom component that retrieves data from a server that when calls `on-render` is loaded

How can I do this? Thanks

Comment: Check my modified answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create factory and show like `MultiLoading.show()` before making API call and `MultiLoading.hide()` after the response is served.

**factory**

```
app.factory('MultiLoading', function($ionicLoading) {
//Loading indicator
var loading = {
    opened: 0,
    show: function() {
        if (loading.opened > 0)
            return;
        $ionicLoading.show({
          noBackdrop :false,
          template: '<ion-spinner icon="ripple"></ion-spinner>',
          duration :20000
      });
        loading.opened+=1;
    },
    hide: function() { 
        loading.opened = 0;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    }
};
return loading;
});
```

Regards.

Comment: I haven't used this but it helped me finding a good solution.
I changed my component to `<mycomp notif="notif" loading="$inc()" loaded="$dec()"></mycomp>` and put `ng-hide="count == 0"` on my spinner. 1 variable `count` in the scope and it's done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use it in Controller

```
$ionicLoading.show({content: 'Loading', animation: 'fade-in',showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200,showDelay: 0});
```

Comment: I'm using `<ion-spinner icon="ripple"></ion-spinner>` because I want a custom spinner, I don't want it to be full page like `$ionicLoading`

Comment: you can use ion-spinner inside the template like  **$ionicLoading.show({ template: '<span class="item-icon-left">Description Cannot be blank... <ion-spinner icon="ripple" class="spinner-royal"/> </span>', animation: 'fade-in',showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200,showDelay: 0,duration: 1000 });**

Comment: Oh, that's nice. In any case, my question isn't about how to make a spinner, but how to know when to hide my it